# JavasScript Object Literal to jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, object-literal

Could someone explain how to convert the following structure into a jQuery plugin - as I'm really struggling here. I'm mainly lost with object properties, methods - how can they be converted to a single plugin:

```
var objLit = {
    thisObj : null,
    propOne : 125,
    propTwo : 300,
    propThree : null,
    methodOne : function(o) {

        if (o.length > 0) {

            objLit.thisObj = o;

            objLit.propOne = o.width();
            objLit.propTwo = o.height();

            objLit.convert();

        }

    },
    convert : function() {
        objLit.thisObj.animate({ 'width' : (objLit.propOne + 20) + 'px', 'height' : (objLit.propTwo + 20) + 'px' }, 300, function() {

            var tout = setTimeout(function() {

                objLit.propOne = (objLit.propOne - 20);
                objLit.propTwo =  (objLit.propTwo - 20);

                objLit.methodTwo();

            }, 2000);

        });
    },
    methodTwo : function() {

        etc...

    }
};
$(function() {

    objLit.methodOne($('.object'));

});
```

The above is just an example of the object literal - wow would we go around converting this into the jQuery plugin?

Comment: Have you read through the jQuery docs on plugin authoring? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Yes - but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? The documentation is pretty straightforward [This](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing) is probably what you want..

Comment: How can I pass options to the specific plugin plugin({ option: 100, etc }), how can I assigned them to the properties of the object, and how can I trigger first method when the object is found on the page - simple questions like this. Copying links to the same page doesn't really do me any good - example would be more appreciated.